# Self bundled web application

Tags: web-applications

I would like to do something basically simple but I don't find the right technology to do so.
In this small web application, you have to fill in forms and so on. Given this input, it will create directories, run scripts, execute programs...
In other words, it should be both client side and server side. People should be able to download the "product", launch the stand-alone server and then access the web interface using their usual browser. Must be usable on linux, preferably cross-platform, without needing installation nor root access, just download and run.

Any suggestions?

PS: any language is OK, PHP, ruby, python...

Comment: Why use web tech for this?  Wouldn't a cross-platform desktop application be more appropriate?

Comment: Mainly because we would like to have this small "tool" available via an intranet but that other external users can also use it for themselves locally by just running a local server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found:

python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000

Or:

python -m CGIHTTPServer 8000

Is already bundled in standard python distributions. Now I just have to figure out how to serve dynamic content with that...

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of options. This kind of question is very broad and there are many potential solutions. One possible idea could be to write your web application (using C/CGI is better for performance against PHP and saves you from having to bundle an interpreter), then bundle it with a server like lighttpd with a special default configuration (custom port, self-contained etc.).

Comment: well, for lighttpd, you have to install stuff, root access, etc. I think I already tried it out. Too cumbersome.

Comment: No, you don't. As long as you bind to a port >=1024, root access is not needed. Also, no installation is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [web2py](http://www.web2py.com), a full-stack Python web framework that's very easy to learn and use. It runs on Linux, Windows, and Mac, requires no installation or configuration, has no dependencies, and includes its own web server. You can easily bundle an app so it can be downloaded, unzipped, and run locally on the user's machine with a single click, without requiring any installation (see http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/12#How-to-Distribute-your-Applications-as-Binaries).

If you have any questions, there's a very friendly and responsive [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/web2py) that will provide lots of help.